# How to find smallest sum of denominators so that sum of fractions is less than or equal to 1, given the numerators?

Tags: optimization, fractions, integer-partitions, integer-programming, divisor-sum

Given $n$ positive integer numbers $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$, how do I find $n$ positive integer numbers $b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n$, so that
$$\frac{a_1}{b_1} + \frac{a_2}{b_2} + \dots + \frac{a_n}{b_n} \leq 1$$
and $b_1 + b_2 + \dots + b_n$ is smallest.

Does this need to be solved by Integer Linear Programming technique? Is there any polynomial time (approximation) algorithm for this?

Comment: I guess you require that all the $b_i$ are positive, or else it's trivial — or impossible, since you would be able to set the $b$'s to arbitrarily large negative numbers.   Or do you mean that you want to minimize the sum of the absolute values in step 2?   Are the $a_i$ guaranteed to be positive, or at least non-negative?

Comment: Have you tried the case $n=2?$  You should be able to solve particular cases by hand.  Try where the $a$'s are very different, like $1,1000$ and where they are similar, like $6,7$.  Does that give any insight?

Comment: @Scott they are positive integers. I have modified the question.

Comment: @RossMillikan`n=1` does make the problem seem like more tractable. But I am not sure if there is any added insight. I am a bit of out of touch with such problems, so it would be good get some pointers.

Comment: `n=2` on that last comment.

Comment: One solution is to make all the $b_i$ equal to the sum of all the $a_i$ plus $1$.  That always works and provides an upper bound on the solution.  For the $n=2$ case you can solve the problem with equality to $1$ in the usual way.  You want to minimize $b_1+b_2$.  Use the sum being $1$ to eliminate one of $b_1$ or $b_2$, then take the derivative, set to zero...

Comment: Okay, thanks. I tried with two numbers $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 1000$. But after derivative, I have $b_1^2 - 2b_1 - 998 = 0$, which would not give me an integer $b_1$. But if I turn that equation to inequality $(b_1 - 1)^2 > 999$, then that would lead me to $b_1 = 33, b_2 = 1032$. 
I am not sure how we can generalize this for $n$ numbers as that would lead to more numbers of inequalities. Is not ILP for that kind optimization?